# Javascript: Reduce spaces in input field form validation

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Ok, I need to achieve five things basically - with JS not jQuery. I've tried several RegExp codes here and none worked for me. Let me start with the first problem (number 1):

1. Remove excess spaces in "userName" input field (i.e. Only space allowed is between first name and last name)

```js
function removeSpaces(str){
  return str.replace(/^\s+/,"").replace(/\s+$/,"").replace(/\s+/g," ");
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="myform" onsubmit="removeSpaces(this)">
       <div id="nameDiv">
           <label for="user_login">User login</label>
           <input id="userName" type="text" name="user_login" value=""> 
       </div>
              
              <div id="submitButton"> 
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="" onclick="validateForm(), removeSpaces(), firstLetterCaps()">
       </div>
              
</body>
</html>
```

2. User must enter at least two names i.e. first and last name
3. Capitalize first letter of each name (should happen when submit button is clicked)
4. Count number of lines as user types in comment - if number of lines is less than 10, indicator (not text) is green, otherwise, it's red.
5. The appropriate hidden errorMessage div should appear instead of an alert JS window. E.g: when user doesn't input name and clicks submit, errorMessageName div should appear.

For number 1, I tried this but it's not working:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  function removeSpaces(nameInput){
   var nameInput = document.getElementById("userName").value;
   return nameInput.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');
    }

 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="nameDiv" style="border: 1px solid red; text-align: center;">

  <label for="user_login">User login</label>
  <input id="userName" type="text" name="" value="" required="" onblur="capitalizeFirstLetter(); removeSpaces()">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help on this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by `Remove excess spaces in "userName"`? what if user enters 5 words?

Comment: I could give you some simple regex's to use for 1) and 2) , but you need to consider whether normalising people's names is really what you want. How should it handle "Pedro da Silva" (whose Surname is not first letter capitalised) or "Jean Michel Dar" (with a first name of two words) or "John O'Reilly"  (with another non-standard capitalisation) or where the family name comes first.

Comment: You are doing this all wrong. It's complex validation, doesn't handle complex names very well like: Edvin van der Sar, etc. Also, its multiple things not a simple question. Split name into 2 or 3 parts (name middle name surname). Don't capitalize anything, just warn the user in case 1 or more names start with a small letter. Trim spaces before after names but don't put a limit on how many words there are, some people have more surnames than one or more names.

Comment: @YossiVainshtein I mean name with spaces must be converted to the same name but without those spaces. For example: "      John                    Digil            " should become -> "John Digil" when submit button is hit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
 function checkAndFormat(nameInput){
    var el = document.getElementById("userName");

    if ( typeof el != "object" ) {
        alert("Cannot find element called 'userName'!");
        return;
    }
    var nameInput = el.value;

    if( typeof nameInput == "string" ) {
      var aryParts = nameInput.split(" "), strFirst, strLast;

      for( var i in aryParts ) {
        var strTerm = aryParts[i].trim();

        if ( strTerm.length == 0 ) {
          continue;
        }        
        strTerm = strTerm.toLowerCase();
        strTerm = strTerm.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + strTerm.substr(1);

        if ( strFirst == undefined ) {
          strFirst = strTerm;
        } else if ( strLast == undefined ) {
          strLast = strTerm;
        }
      }
      if ( typeof strFirst == "string" && typeof strLast == "string" ) {
        el.value = strFirst + " " + strLast;
        return;
      }
    }
    throw("Please enter first name and last name!");
}
// -->
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="nameDiv" style="border: 1px solid red; text-align: center;">

  <label for="user_login">User login</label>
  <input id="userName" type="text" name="" value="" required="" onblur="checkAndFormat();">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but surely there has to be a simpler JS code for this. This seems complex.

Comment: Maybe, but this is robust and won't fall over, and its readable!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function onSubmit(element) {
errorElement = document.getElementById("error");
errorElement.innerHTML = "";
elements = element.querySelectorAll("label > input, label > textarea");
words = elements[0].value.match(/\S+/g) || [];
if(words.length < 2) {
  document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "<br>Name must be at least 2 words."
  return false;
}
words = words.map(function(word) {
return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1);
});
elements[0].value = words.join(" ");
}

function onUpdate(element) {
}
```

```css
div#error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return onSubmit(this);">
<label>Name:<br><input type="text" name="userName"/></label>
<br><br>
<label>Comments:<br><textarea name="comment" onchange="onUpdate"></textarea></label>
<br><br>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<div id="error"></div>
```

Got everything but 4.